# Show that inf $f(x)$ is achieved. Find $\inf f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, differential-topology, lagrange-multiplier

Let $$\Sigma = \{x\in R^3: x_1x_2 +x_1x_3 +x_2x_3=1 \}$$

and $$f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \frac{9}{2} x_3^2$$

a)  Show that $\Sigma$ is a smooth surface in $R^3$.

b) Show that $\inf_{x\in\Sigma}$ f(x) is achieved.  Find $\inf_{x\in\Sigma}  f(x)$.

For part (a), since this is an old advanced calculus (introductory, non-measure -theoretic analysis) exam question, I am not sure how much proof is required, other than to make the observation that the set is a level set of a smooth function, g, in the variables $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.  I've read up a bit on how to prove surfaces are "smooth", but that material uses a bit of differential topology, namely, the "constant rank theorem".  I think that would be unnecessary, but feel free to comment and offer a suggestion -- or even answer part(a) with a proof, if you'd like to give one.

For part(b), to both show that the infimum is achieved and to find it, I considered a set of equations, using the method of Lagrange multipliers:

$$2x_1 = \lambda (x_2+x_3)$$
$$2x_2 = \lambda (x_1+x_3)$$
$$9x_3 = \lambda (x_1+x_2)$$
$$g=x_1x_2 +x_1x_3 +x_2x_3=1$$

I am stuck at this point.  I have tried subtracting equations, which didn't lead to much.  My other attempt was to multiply the first equation by $x_2$, the second equation by $x_3$, and the third equation by $x_1$, and then adding these three new equations gives a single equation, where I can use the constraint $x_1x_2 +x_1x_3 +x_2x_3=1$.  This method didn't turn out very well either.

Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Comment on (a): your reasoning would apply equally well to the surface defined by $x_1x_2x_3=0$, but I don't think that qualifies as a smooth surface. I think you have to check something about partial derivatives not simultaneously vanishing.

Comment: Comment for (b): the first three equations are linear in $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ (treating $\lambda$ like a constant for the moment); you can use linear algebra to show that for most values of $\lambda$, there are no nontrivial solutions to those equations. That will narrow down the possibilities for $\lambda$; for each possibility, you can use the parametrization of the solution set to plug into the last equation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @GregMartin.  I will revisit part(a), but for now I will try the linear algebraic method that you've suggested for part(b).

Comment: As a comment to Greg Martin's comment on (a), I want to explain why the surface $x_1x_2x_3=0$ is not a smooth surface.  The reason is that $0$ is not a regular value of $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)\mapsto x_1x_2x_3$.  The preimage of this function at $0$ contains the point $(0,0,0)$, at which the differential is given by the zero matrix $[0\;\;0\;\;0]$.  Hence, this function is not a submersion at $(0,0,0)$.  However, if we remove the origin from the preimage, you will get a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Just realized my mistake, you have to remove the $x_1$-, $x_2$-, and $x_3$-axes from the surface $x_1x_2x_3=0$ to get a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$.  Any point with two zero coordinates is  not a regular point for the function $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)\mapsto x_1x_2x_3$.

Comment: Indeed, one must remove the three coordinate planes - the $x_1x_2$-plane, the $x_2x_3$-plane, and the $x_1x_3$-plane.

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, I have solved part(b), agreeing with Batominovski's answer, but using the linear algebraic way that you suggested, since I don't think I would be clever enough to show quickly the upper bound of f, as the answer below does in the beginning.  Can I ask you a follow-up question for part(a)?  I thought about what you had said, and then I computed the gradient of the constraint function, g.  I noticed that grad(g) must never vanish on this level set, since g = 1.

Comment: Then can I sort of use an Inverse Function Theorem argument and say that, since g is $C^1$, and its total derivative never vanishes, then at every point on the level set g=1, there exists a local inverse, $g^{-1}$?  And, by the IFT, the inverse is also of class $C^1$.  It seems like the theorem may not be applicable, because I didn't take a "Jacobian determinant" of my *non-square matrix* of partial derivatives.

Comment: You don't want to try to define $g^{-1}$ on the set of points where $g=1$ - that's the least injective you can possibly get....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), $1$ is a regular value of $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)\mapsto x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2$.  That is, at every point $p$ in $f^{-1}(1)$, $f$ is a submersion at $p$.  In other words, $\text{d}_pf:\text{T}_p\mathbb{R}^3\to\text{T}_1\mathbb{R}$ is surjective.  This can be easily seen since the matrix representing $\text{d}_pf$ (you probably call it $Df(p)$) is
$$\left[x_2+x_3\;\;\;x_3+x_1\;\;x_1+x_2\right]\Big|_{\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=p}\,.$$
This matrix certainly has a nonzero entry.  Now, by the Regular Value Theorem (see, for example, [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mat1300/smoothmaps.4.pdf)), $f^{-1}(1)$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (of dimension $2$).

For (b), note that 
$$\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+\frac{9}{2}x_3^2\right)-\frac{3}{2}\left(x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2\right)=\frac{3}{4}\left(x_1-x_2\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(x_1-3x_3\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(x_2-3x_3\right)^2\geq0\,.$$
Hence, if $x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2=1$, then
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+\frac{9}{2}x_3^2\geq \frac{3}{2}\,.$$
The equality holds if and only if $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=\pm\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}\right)$.

You can continue with your attempt with Lagrange multipliers as follows.
If $\lambda=0$, then all the $x_i$'s are zero, which is clearly not a feasible point.  Hence, $\lambda\neq 0$.  The equations $2x_1=\lambda\left(x_2+x_3\right)$ and $2x_2=\lambda\left(x_1+x_3\right)$ imply that
$$2x_1\left(x_1+x_3\right)=2x_2\left(x_2+x_3\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$\left(x_1-x_2\right)\left(x_1+x_2+x_3\right)=0\,.$$

*Case I*: $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$.  Then, $9x_3=\lambda\left(x_1+x_2\right)=-\lambda x_3$ leads to $\lambda=-9$ or $x_3=0$, whilst $2x_1=\lambda\left(x_2+x_3\right)=-\lambda x_1$ and $2x_2=\lambda\left(x_1+x_3\right)=-\lambda x_2$ mean that either $\lambda=-2$ or both $x_1$ and $x_2$ equal $0$. However, if two of the variables are zero, then $x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2=0$, making the point infeasible.  Hence, $\lambda=-2$ and $x_3=0$, which means $x_1+x_2=x_1+x_2+x_3=0$.  That is, $1=x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2=-x_1^2\leq 0$, which is absurd.

*Case II*: $x_1+x_2+x_3\neq 0$.  Then, $x_1=x_2$.  Write $a$ for the common value of $x_1$ and $x_2$.  We get $9x_3=\lambda\left(x_1+x_2\right)=2a\lambda$, or $x_3=\frac{2a\lambda}{9}$.  Trivially, $a\neq 0$ (otherwise, we would get a contradiction with $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$).  Also, $2a=2x_1=\lambda\left(x_1+x_3\right)=\lambda\left(a+\frac{2a\lambda}{9}\right)$ yields 
$$2=\lambda\left(1+\frac{2\lambda}{9}\right)\text{ or }\lambda\in\left\{-6,\frac{3}{2}\right\}\,.$$
If $\lambda=-6$, then $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=\left(a,a,-\frac{4}{3}a\right)$, so that $1=x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2=-\frac{5}{3}a^2\leq 0$, which is absurd.  Hence, $\lambda=\frac{3}{2}$, or $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=\left(a,a,\frac{1}{3}a\right)$.  As $1=x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2=\frac{5}{3}a^2$, we get $a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}=\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}}$.

In summary, we have that $\lambda=\frac{3}{2}$ and that $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=\pm\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}\right)$ are critical points of $x_1^2+x_2^2+\frac{9}{2}x_3^2$ subject to $x_2x_3+x_3x_1+x_1x_2=1$.  Since $x_1^2+x_2^2+\frac{9}{2}x_3^2$ is bounded below, and the existence of these critical points implies that either of them must be a minimizing point.  It turns out that both points correspond to the same value, whence they are both minimizing points.

Comment: Hi @batominovski, thanks so much for your solution -- especially the very clever upper bound that you derived in the beginning of your part(b) solution.  I got the same result as you: 3/2, but using the full-out Lagrange method.  But, as I had mentioned to GregMartin (above), if I couldn't show that upper bound like you did, how would I know that my *two* critical points, both giving a value of 3/2, under the mapping of f, are where f attains a minimum?  Why wouldn't 3/2 be a max of f, on this level set? Thanks for your time,

Comment: (If the two critical points gave two *different* values of f, then the comparison is trivial, and we'd know which point gives f the minimum.)

Comment: You can easily see that $f$ is not bounded above on $\Sigma$.  All points of the form $\left(t,\frac{1}{t},0\right)$ are in $\Sigma$.  Hence, among the critical points obtained, the one with the lower value is the minimizing point.  As it turns out, both give the same value, whence they are both minimizing points.

Comment: Ahhh...yes, of course :-)

Comment: My answer for part(a) is similar to yours, but I don't use any differential topology but instead showed that the gradient is non-vanishing on the level set, just as you pointed out that your matrix is guaranteed to have a non-zero entry.  Can I "apply" the Inverse Function Theorem and say that g has a local inverse, at every point p, on this level set.  Hence, since g is of class $C^1$, then its inverse is also of class $C^1$, and g is a smooth mapping, which implies the level set is a smooth surface.  What do you think?  Thanks for your time,

Comment: Although, I didn't take a "Jacobian determinant" of my non-square matrix.  And also, I'm using "smooth" here to mean $C^1$, and not $C^{\infty}$.   I wonder whether I am using the word "smooth" correctly.  E.g., in complex analysis, smooth functions are obviously $C^{\infty}$, but in real variable calculus, is $C^1$ enough to consider a map "smooth"?  Thanks, @batominovski.

Comment: Well, the Regular Value Theorem is essentially built on the Inverse Function Theorem.  I am not sure what your $g$ is, but if my guess is right (that is, $g$ is some nice map from an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to an open set containing $p$ on $\Sigma$), you should be able to show that $g$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, whence $\Sigma$ is smooth.

Comment: Oh, I just took my g to be the constraint function, $x_1x_2 +x_1x_3 +x_2x_3$, so that $x_1x_2 +x_1x_3 +x_2x_3=1$ is a level set of the graph of g.  Then I computed the gradient of g, which matches your 1x3 matrix.  Then, from the constraint, g =1, we see that the gradient must be non-vanishing everywhere on the level set.  Maybe there is a key point I am missing here regarding the local inverse:  g is $C^{\infty}$, right?  Because it's just a linear function in three variables.  Polynomials are also $C^{\infty}$, for example.  Then by the IFT, the inverse is **of the same class**, right?

Comment: Then, as you are probably implying all along, we know that $g^{-1}$ is also $C^{\infty}$.  Hence the set of x in $R^3$ that we are looking at, is a smooth surface.  Although, learning the IFT in class lectures and in textbooks, we only learned that if g is $C^1$, then the inverse is also $C^1$.  So, we can generalize to $C^{\infty}$, I think.  What do you think, @batominovski?  Thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: If $g$ is $\mathcal{C}^k$, then a more general version of IFT would state that $g^{-1}$ is also $\mathcal{C}^k$.  Hence, if $g$ is smooth, it also has a smooth inverse.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for your time and patience.  I learned a lot from you in this problem :-).  Have a great night, @Batominovski!!